# Wondering if there's a way to stop an mjpeg stream being output by PHP

Tags: php, mjpeg

I am outputting an MJPEG stream through PHP, so that the direct link to the stream does not appear publicly on a website (I just link to this file as an intermediary).
The code works, and is as follows:

```
header('Content-type: video/x-motion-jpeg');
$server = "server.com";
$port = "8080";
$url = "/mjpg/Cam1/video.mjpg";
set_time_limit(30); // Doesn't affect the streaming timeout
$fp = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30); // The timeout set here doesn't affect the streaming timeout
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
} else {
    $urlstring = "GET ".$url." HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    fputs ($fp, $urlstring);
    while ($str = trim(fgets($fp, 4096))){
        header($str);
    }
    fpassthru($fp);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

What I am wondering is if there's a way I can kill this stream (server-side, not client-side) after a certain duration (ex: 5 minutes).
I'm open to using different code/functions if required, or approaching this in a different way.

Comment: Instead of using `fpassthru`, write a loop that calls `fread()` and checks the time in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from @Barmar , I wrote a loop that calls fread() and checks the time in each iteration until the timeout is reached. So far it's doing the trick.

The code is as follows:

```
$timeout = 5; // seconds
$fp = fsockopen($server, $port, $errno, $errstr, 5); // The timeout set here doesn't affect the streaming timeout
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br>\n";
} else {
    $urlstring = "GET ".$url." HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    fputs ($fp, $urlstring);
    while ($str = trim(fgets($fp, 4096))){
        header($str);                   
    }
    $start = time();
    $now = time();
    while ( $now - $start < $timeout ) {
        echo fread( $fp, 4096 );
        $now = time();
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```